# keeping ISO constant in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, avfoundation, iso

Is there any way to keep ISO value constant? I am designing an app for image capture in iOS.
I am changing exposure ratio by selecting different metering points, but it changes both exposure ratio and ISO. Is there a way to decouple these things?

Comment: Have you tried anything you've read in the [AV Foundation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5)?

Comment: The firmware controls the ISO and exposure time. You'll notice that the AV Foundation docs don't mention those items.